# Sequence does not reset after truncating the table

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I use SELECT lastval() to get wrong serial id  after truncated  the table.

when I truncate the table, I use SELECT lastval(), I got the wrong ID/

Answer (score 100):

Use the `TRUNCATE` SQL command.

For a single table the syntax is the following:

```sql
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name RESTART IDENTITY;
```

For multiple tables:

```sql
TRUNCATE TABLE table_foo, table_bar RESTART IDENTITY;
```

What it does:

> Automatically restart sequences owned by columns of the truncated table(s).

Details here: [TRUNCATE @ postgresql.org](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html)

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RESTART"
LINE 1: truncate table product RESTART IDENTITY;

Comment: @user1369887 What version of PostgreSQL do you have?

Comment: My server version is : server 8.3.16

Comment: Similar thing happens on verion 8.4.9.
Following statment does not reset sequence value:
`TRUNCATE TABLE my_table RESTART IDENTITY;`

Comment: @Wojtas Read the answer carefully. It already states, that it will only reset sequences **owned by columns of the truncated table**.

Answer (score 24):

Following is the standard way to reset sequence:

```
truncate table table_name restart identity;
```

but in some version & platform, it's syntax error,

in that case, you can truncate without reset sequence, and alter the sequence with another sql, try this:

```
truncate table table_name;
alter sequence seq_name start 1;
```

Answer (score 8):

The best way to reset a sequence to start back with number 1 is to execute the following after you have successfully truncate it:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE <tablename>_<id>_seq RESTART WITH 1
```

So, for example for the users table it would be:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE users_id_seq RESTART WITH 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Helped. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

`TRUNCATE TABLE table_name RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;`

Comment: Don't cascade unless you know what it does and you are sure that's what you want to do

Answer (score 4):

Check the next

```
ALTER SEQUENCE sequence_name RESTART WITH 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reset the sequence then:

```
setval('sequence_name', 0)
```

To list the existent sequence names issue a `\ds` at the psql prompt.

Comment: Note that for programmatic identification of a field's sequence there's the function pg_get_serial_sequence.  select pg_get_serial_sequence('tablename','colname');

Comment: Wrong ID means, It is not actual generating ID value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below sql statement to reset the identity in postgresql:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name RESTART IDENTITY;
```

But note, it's not possible to reseed the identity in Redshift. The way around to reset in Redshift is to drop and then create the table again.