# postgreSQL: primary key doesn't start on 1

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment, database-sequence

I made a primary key called t_id in the table of DB by using the query  `t_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`.
At the very first time, it started well on 1. Then I deleted all the data and from then, it starts on 2 even though I set it on 1.

Here's the screenshot of what I did on seq - definition on pgAdmin4 :

[image]

Anyone has an idea where is the problem ?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: if  current value = 1, next value (Which is generated by  record insertion into table) will be 2

Comment: I tried to set it on 0, then it shows an error msg of setval saying the value should be between 1 and 2147483647

Comment: Use truncate instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989243/sequence-does-not-reset-after-truncating-the-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current value is 1, so the next value that will be served is 2. This is expected.

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) is helpful on this topic.

Remember that the sequence will always give you a value that was not used before. So if you insert 10 rows, then delete them, the next sequence value will still be 11 (the last served value + 1)

To reset the sequence so the next time it is called it returns 1, you would do

```
SELECT setval('my_sequence_name', 1, false);
```

Comment: I , of course,  tried to set it on 0, then it shows an error msg of setval saying the value should be between 1 and 2147483647.

Answer (score 0):

Your `t_id` is a primary key auto incremented serial type. These are sequenced, you can set the value of the next sequence using the sequence manipulation functions.

[Postgres sequence manipulation functions documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html)